# Ionic ion-sticky not working with iOS 11

Tags: ios, angular, css, ionic3

I am using ionic version 3.12.1, I used this to stick particular division, and it seems to be working with **iOS 10** and below version but not working in **iOS 11**

I make the use of the below mention CSS.

```
.sticky{
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top:0px;
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: did you solved?